# Can I get some 3D model file(s) from 3D ultrasound?

Tags: printing, 3d, dicom

do you know anybody if it is possible to get some model file from doctor when he made 3d ultrasound of pregnant woman? I mean something like DICOM (.dcm) file or .stl file or something like that what I can then work with and finaly print with 3D printer.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you had the scan? Check with the clinics to see if they will give you files and then find out the format.

Answer (score 0):

Quick search for "dicom 3d ultrasound sample" resulted in one that you might be able to use for internal testing. You can get the file from [here](http://www.insight-journal.org/midas/item/view/943)

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour,

The first problem you will face is the file format.

Because of the way the images are generated, 3D ultrasound data have voxels that are expressed in a spherical system. DICOM (as it stand now) only support voxels in a Cartesian system.

So the manufacturers have a few choices:

- They can save the data in proprietary format (ex: Kretzfile for Ge, MVL for Samsung).
- They can save the data in private tags inside a DICOM file (Ge, Hitachi, Philips)
- They can re-format the voxels to be in Cartesian, but then the data has been transformed and nobody like that. And anyway, since they also need to save the original (untransformed) data, the companies that do offer Cartesian voxels, usually save them in the same way as the original, so they are not saved in normal DICOM tags, but in their proprietary version.

This is why most of the standard software that can do 3D from CT or MR will not be able to cope with the data files.

Then the second problem is the noise. Ultrasound datasets are inherently very noisy! Again standard 3D reconstruction software where designed for CT or MR and have problems with this.

I do have a product that will read most of the 3D ultrasound files and create an STL model directly from the datasets (spherical or Cartesian). It is called baby SliceO (http://www.tomovision.com/products/baby_sliceo.html)

Unfortunately, it is not free, but you can try it without any licenses. Give it a try and let me know if you like it...

Yves